# Pop up Terminal app with running commands on login

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

I want on each users login to make the terminal pop up and say
"Please press ENTER to continue"

and I've tried all the ways I know, maybe i'm missing something...

I do not want to add it to 'startup application service' since I want it
to be dynamically on each user login, and not define on any specific userid beforehand.

so that leaves me with things like /etc/bash.bashrc or /etc/skel/.bashrc
or /etc/profile or /etc/init.d/ (with /etc/rc#.d/ )
and none of these methods working for me

for example I'm doing this:
created a shell file - first_login and its content simple:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ ! -e "$HOME/.first_login_done" ]; then
    x-terminal-emulator -e /etc/skel/first_login.sh
    touch "$HOME/.first_login_done"
fi
```

as seen here, creating a marking file .first_login_done
so it will be only on first login of each user.

so its check if the file exists in $HOME and if not, execute the /etc/skel/first_login.sh

(nvm the x-termina-emulator -e its just the latest, i also tried 'source' and a simple ./ )

nothing works for me, although when I'm executing using for example 'source /etc/init.d/first_login' or else like 'source /etc/rc2.d/first_login'
that does pop up a new terminal window with the msg "Please press ENTER to continue"
but on restart\relogin that does not happen. the terminal app does not pop at all.
even when there is no $HOME/.first_login_don marking, which means it should work, but it does not.

anything I'm missing perhaps?
thanks advance for the helpers.

Comment: Have you tried placing your script in /etc/profile.d/ ?  Make sure to chmod +x /etc/profile.d/yourscript.sh

Comment: *"... so it will be only on first login of each user."* AND *"but on restart\relogin that does not happen."* seem contradictory to me. What do you mean by *first login of each user*, **first login EVER*", or "first login for the day OR ??"? Once the message has appeared, why do you think it should reappear after *"restart\relogin"*? Please clarify in the body of your question above, rather than making an increasingly long thread of comments for readers (-;!... Good luck!

Comment: AND rather than say *"I've tried all the ways I know"*, SHOW what you have tried. (I know you have included some code). Show the code (or codes) you really expected to work, and make it so readers can copy paste into their environment and witness the same problem. SO read about [mcve] and read the section [How to turn a bad script into a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info) (this advice applies to all languages, not just bash).

Comment: @shellter thanks for the attempts, I think I've managed on my own by creating .desktop on /etc/xdg/autostart and added the code I need inside it. works good now.